# How to wrap error trace inside Log.Severe()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

I am using `java.util.logging.Logger` for logging on app-engine. Normally all I have to do to get my errors is to call `e.printStackTrace()`. Except I get nothing when I make the call from inside a worker thread that belongs to a `Task Queue`. But within the Task Queue, all the loggings done with `LOG.info()` are showing. So my question is: how do I wrap a stack trace inside `LOG.severe()`? The following shows the address instead of the trace itself:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LuceneWorker.class.getName());

//later inside a method
LOG.severe(e.getStackTrace().toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Logger#severe(msg)` is just a convenience method for `Logger#log(Level.SEVERE, msg)`  Use that method instead.

```
LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Your Log Message", e);
```